# Cosa sono i "literni" in questo passaggio?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La madre* di Grazia Deledda (pagina 105 di Edizioni Il Maestrale, ISBN 978-88-89801-42-0) ho letto:

> Taceva anche lui, adesso: pareva si fosse dimenticato perché era lì, e ascoltasse solo il mormorìo del vento fra i **literni**, che pareva il lontano sciabordìo del mare. D’improvviso il cane della guardia balzò abbaiando, e Antioco sentì sopra la sua testa un fruscìo d’ali: si volse a guardare e vide sulle rocce l’aquila addomesticata del vecchio cacciatore, col suo becco forte come un piccolo corno e i ventagli neri delle grandi ali che si aprivano e si sbattevano lentamente.

Qualcuno di voi mi saprebbe spiegare il significato di questi "literni" che appaiono nel brano sopra citato? Ho cercato il termine "literno" su parecchi dizionari, ma non l'ho trovato. Beh, sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI07/GDLI_07_ocr_713.pdf&parola=literno), ho visto questa citazione di Donato degli Albanzani:

> Literno,  luogo  aspro, solitario  e  incolto.

Tuttavia, penso che faccia riferimento a [Literno come nome proprio](https://books.google.es/books?id=3XLpCmPXH2QC&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=literno+dizionario&source=bl&ots=sUs-CAK8Kr&sig=ACfU3U1VmwQrHdhi2I85JyT9VBvN6qZjoQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTrt6hiOTiAhUOlxQKHQMXAcMQ6AEwBHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=literno%20dizionario&f=false) (che appare anche [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=wsDVD4EjeO0C&pg=PA981&lpg=PA981&dq=literno+dizionario&source=bl&ots=lbroEZM2BF&sig=ACfU3U0ei8-2ARb7GQHqlcx9eOEr1acw1w&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZo4mFi-TiAhVy8eAKHSDoAQY4ChDoATAAegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=literno%20dizionario&f=false)).

Answer (score 2):

Ho cercato il tuo passaggio nel libro e ho visto che in [questa edizione](https://www.classicistranieri.com/liberliber/Deledda,%20Grazia/la_ma_p.pdf) al posto di *literni* viene invece riportato il termine **linterni**.

Cercando in rete ho trovato il termine [linterno](http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/L/linterno.aspx?query=linterno), con il seguente significato:

> **linterno**
>   
>  > [lin-tèr-no]
>   
>  > s.m.
>   
>  > BOT Arbusto della famiglia delle Ramacee (Rhamnus alaternus), con
>   foglie lucenti e fusto a drupa rossa o nera

Il [Rhamus alaternus](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhamnus_alaternus) il cui nome italiano è Alaterno, Ranno
lanterno, Linterno, Purrolo o Ilatro, è un arbusto sempreverde, della
famiglia delle Rhamnaceae.

Comment: Quindi, a quanto pare, si tratta semplicemente di un refuso.

Comment: @Charo Sì, a quanto pare. Per scrupolo verifica con esattezza il termine riportato nella tua edizione del libro.

Comment: L'ho già fatto, @abarisone, e anche su [questa pagina di Wikisource](https://it.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Pagina:La_madre_(1920).djvu/141) (vedi la fotografia) si trova un'altra edizione in cui si legge anche "literni".

Comment: Bisognerebbe guardare la prima edizione. Non sarebbe la prima volta che un termine viene scritto “sbagliato” perché acquisito male: più o meno a tutti è capitato, per qualche termine insolito, di scoprire che non è come lo si era imparato.

Comment: @egreg: A quanto pare, la [versione di Wikisource](https://it.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Indice:La_madre_(1920).djvu) corrisponde alla prima edizione in volume, quella di Fratelli Treves, Editori (Milano, 1920). Secondo [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_madre_(Deledda)), il romanzo è stato precedentemente (1919) pubblicato a puntate nel giornale *Il tempo*.